# Алиасы (псевдонимы) пути для `basePath` в Yii2

Tags: yii2

В [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#basePath) сказано:

> You may configure the basePath property using a directory path or a path alias. ...

Про какие алиасы идёт речь, если, как я понимаю, они (алиасы) и базируются (инициализируется) на значении `basePath`?

Comment: нет/ алиасов несколько `@webroot`, `@vendor`, `@app`, `@yii`, `@runtime` и пр..... они указывают на какую-либо директорию, с которой начинается что-то.....`@app` - как раз базовый путь..... вот и вы можете придумать свой алиас например `@rahamBahaRamamburu` и установить на что он будет указывать...................https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/concept-aliases.md

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это я понимаю: что есть разные алиасы и что можно установить свои алиасы либо через `Yii::setAlias()`, либо через свойство [`aliases`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#aliases) самого приложения. Мне непонятно как можно использовать алиас в качестве значения свойства приложения `basePath` ...

Comment: наверное как-то так `'aliases' => [
        '@mybasepath' => '@app/path/to/my/base/folder',
],`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это для свойства `aliases` — и это понятно. А я имею в виду `basePath` ... Ведь в доках сказано: `using a directory path or a path alias` ... Как можно использовать `path alias` для свойства `basePath` — вот это неясно?